# Box2D moving body to a different position when collided

Tags: java, libgdx

I have two bodies, a dynamic and a kinematic body. When these collided with each other, I want to change the position of the kinematic body. I added a Contact Listener and I am able to detect the collision. But when I want to change the transform of the kinematic body, my game crashes.
I would really apprechiate your help.

Error: AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Assertion failed!

Program: D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe
File: /var/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/libgdx/extensions/gdx-box2d/gdx-box2d/jni/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.cpp, Line 419

Expression: m_world->IsLocked() == false

```
public class Player extends Sprite {
public static final float scale = 12;
public static final float moveSpeed = 110;
public Body b2body;

public Player(World world) {
    super(new Texture("playercut.jpg"));
    setBounds(0,0,getWidth() / (FishAdventureMain.PPM * Player.scale), getHeight() / (FishAdventureMain.PPM * Player.scale));
    BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bdef.position.set(650/FishAdventureMain.PPM, 200 / FishAdventureMain.PPM);
    b2body = world.createBody(bdef);
    shape.setAsBox(getWidth() / 3, getHeight() / 5);
    fdef.shape = shape;
    b2body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData("head");
}

public void update() {
    super.setPosition(b2body.getPosition().x - getWidth()/2, (b2body.getPosition().y - getHeight()/2) + (float)Math.sin(System.currentTimeMillis() * 0.009) * 0.04f);
}
```

}

```
public class AbstractGameObj {
protected final float moveSpeed = 90;
private Sprite sprite;
protected World world;
protected Body body;
protected Fixture fixture;
protected Vector2 position;

public AbstractGameObj(World world, Sprite sprite, Vector2 position, float scaleFactor1, float scaleFactor2) {
    this.world = world;
    this.sprite = sprite;
    this.position = position;

    BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
    bdef.position.set(position);
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.KinematicBody;
    body = world.createBody(bdef);
    shape.setAsBox(sprite.getWidth() / scaleFactor1, sprite.getHeight() / scaleFactor2);
    fdef.shape = shape;
    fixture = body.createFixture(fdef);
}
public void update(float dt) {
    sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x - sprite.getWidth()/2, body.getPosition().y - sprite.getWidth() / 2);
    body.setLinearVelocity(moveSpeed *dt, 0);
}
public void onCollision() {

}
public Sprite getSprite() { return this.sprite; }
```

}

```
public class Coconut extends AbstractGameObj{

public Coconut(World world, Sprite sprite, Vector2 position, float scaleFactor1, float scaleFactor2) {
    super(world, sprite, position, scaleFactor1, scaleFactor2);
    fixture.setUserData(this);
}

@Override
public void onCollision() {
    body.setTransform(100, 100, body.getAngle());
}
```

}

```
public class B2WorldCreator {

private Sprite cocoSprite1;
private Sprite cocoSprite2;

private Array<Coconut> cocoNuts;

public B2WorldCreator(World world) {
    //Border bottom
    BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();

    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    bdef.position.set(0, 0);
    shape.setAsBox(FishAdventureMain.V_WIDTH / FishAdventureMain.PPM, 1 / FishAdventureMain.PPM);
    fdef.shape = shape;
    world.createBody(bdef).createFixture(fdef);

    //Border Top
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    bdef.position.set(0, FishAdventureMain.V_HEIGHT / FishAdventureMain.PPM);
    shape.setAsBox(FishAdventureMain.V_WIDTH / FishAdventureMain.PPM, 1 / FishAdventureMain.PPM);
    fdef.shape = shape;
    world.createBody(bdef).createFixture(fdef);

    //Border left
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    bdef.position.set(FishAdventureMain.V_WIDTH / FishAdventureMain.PPM, FishAdventureMain.V_HEIGHT / FishAdventureMain.PPM);
    shape.setAsBox(1 / FishAdventureMain.PPM, FishAdventureMain.V_HEIGHT / FishAdventureMain.PPM);
    fdef.shape = shape;
    world.createBody(bdef).createFixture(fdef);

    //Border kind of middle
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    bdef.position.set(200 / FishAdventureMain.PPM, 0);
    shape.setAsBox(1 / FishAdventureMain.PPM, FishAdventureMain.V_HEIGHT / FishAdventureMain.PPM);
    fdef.shape = shape;
    world.createBody(bdef).createFixture(fdef);

    //Coconuts
    cocoNuts = new Array<Coconut>();
    cocoSprite1 = new Sprite(new Texture("coconut.jpg"));
    cocoSprite1.setBounds(0,0, cocoSprite1.getWidth() / FishAdventureMain.PPM/10, cocoSprite1.getHeight() / FishAdventureMain.PPM/10);
    cocoSprite2 = new Sprite(new Texture("coconut.jpg"));
    cocoSprite2.setBounds(0,0, cocoSprite2.getWidth() / FishAdventureMain.PPM/10, cocoSprite2.getHeight() / FishAdventureMain.PPM/10);
    cocoNuts.add(new Coconut(world, cocoSprite1, new Vector2(-300 / FishAdventureMain.PPM, 2), 1.8f, 1.8f));
    cocoNuts.add(new Coconut(world, cocoSprite2, new Vector2(-1800 / FishAdventureMain.PPM, 2), 1.8f, 1.8f));

}
public void updateCocoNuts(float dt) {
    for (Coconut nut : cocoNuts) {
        nut.update(dt);
    }
}
public void showCocoNuts(SpriteBatch sb) {
    for (Coconut nut : cocoNuts) {
        nut.getSprite().draw(sb);
    }
}
```

}

```
public class PlayScreen extends InputAdapter implements Screen {
private FishAdventureMain main;
private OrthographicCamera gameCam;
private Viewport gamePort;
private Hud hud;
private ButtonController bcont;
private Texture background;
private World world;
private Box2DDebugRenderer renderer;
private Player player;
private B2WorldCreator creator;

public PlayScreen(FishAdventureMain main) {
    this.main = main;
    gameCam = new OrthographicCamera();
    gamePort = new StretchViewport(FishAdventureMain.V_WIDTH / FishAdventureMain.PPM, FishAdventureMain.V_HEIGHT / FishAdventureMain.PPM, gameCam);
    hud = new Hud(main.batch);
    bcont = new ButtonController(main.batch);
    background = new Texture("background.jpg");
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), true);
    creator = new B2WorldCreator(world);
    renderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    player = new Player(world);
    gameCam.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth()/2, gamePort.getWorldHeight()/2,0);
    world.setContactListener(new ContactListener() {
        @Override
        public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
            Fixture fixA = contact.getFixtureA();
            Fixture fixB = contact.getFixtureB();

            if (fixA.getUserData() == "head" || fixB.getUserData() == "head") {
                Fixture head = fixA.getUserData() == "head" ? fixA : fixB;
                Fixture object = head == fixA ? fixB : fixA;
                if (object.getUserData() != null && AbstractGameObj.class.isAssignableFrom(object.getUserData().getClass())) {
                    ((AbstractGameObj) object.getUserData()).onCollision();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void endContact(Contact contact) {

        }

        @Override
        public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {

        }

        @Override
        public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void show() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0,0,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    main.batch.setProjectionMatrix(gamePort.getCamera().combined);
    main.batch.begin();
    main.batch.draw(background, 0, 0, FishAdventureMain.V_WIDTH / FishAdventureMain.PPM, FishAdventureMain.V_HEIGHT / FishAdventureMain.PPM);
    player.draw(main.batch);
    creator.showCocoNuts(main.batch);
    main.batch.end();
    renderer.render(world, gameCam.combined);

    main.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);
    hud.stage.draw();
    bcont.stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    update(delta);
    show();
}

public void update(float dt) {
    handleInput(dt);
    world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);
    gameCam.update();
    player.update();
    creator.updateCocoNuts(dt);
}

private void handleInput(float dt) {
    if (bcont.getUpPressed())
        player.b2body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x, Player.moveSpeed * dt));
    else if (bcont.getDownPressed())
        player.b2body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x, -Player.moveSpeed * dt));
    else
        player.b2body.setLinearVelocity(player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x, 0);
    if(bcont.getLeftPressed())
        player.b2body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(-Player.moveSpeed * dt, player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().y));
    else if (bcont.getRightPressed())
        player.b2body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(Player.moveSpeed * dt, player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().y));
    else
        player.b2body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(0, player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().y));
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    gamePort.update(width, height);
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    background.dispose();
    hud.dispose();
}
```

}

Comment: What's the exception which causes the crash?  Where's your code?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) 3) Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: Now you can see my code and the exception. I am looking forward to get your solution

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is that you are trying to move an object during the physics processing. Box2D doesn't like object being moved or altered during the physics processing(e.g. during collisions)

In order to get around this issue, you have to set a flag for your collided object and then move it once the physics is completed.

e.g.

```
// during physics processing
@Override
public void onCollision() {
    //add body to array of objects to move
}
```

and then add

```
 public void update(float dt) {
    handleInput(dt);
    world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);
    // world is done processing physics
    // loop through array and move objects
    gameCam.update();
    player.update();
    creator.updateCocoNuts(dt);
}
```